# Ninject dispose order with InRequestScope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

Just started playing with ninject - and I can't get past this issue. Consider this setup:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
   kernel.Bind<IDataTransaction>().To<DataTransaction>().InRequestScope();

   kernel.Bind<IdbAnalytics>().To<dbAnalytics>().InRequestScope();
   kernel.Bind<IdbMembership>().To<dbMembership>().InRequestScope();

   kernel.Bind<IAnalyticsWork>().To<AnalyticsWork>().InRequestScope();
   kernel.Bind<IMembershipWork>().To<MembershipWork>().InRequestScope();

   kernel.Bind<ILog>().To<Log>().InRequestScope();
   ...
}
```

With Log being injected into the above classes:

```
public class AnalyticsWork : IAnalyticsWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IdbAnalytics _Context;
    private readonly ILog _Log;

    public AnalyticsWork(IdbAnalytics Context, ILog Log)
    {            
        _Context = Context;
        _Log = Log;
        _Log.Write(LogEntryType.DEBUG, "Object Created");
    }
    ...
}
```

This issue is the Log object gets disposed of ahead of the other objects (AnalyticsWork / MembershipWork). Is there any way to set the order that items should be disposed of? Or is this setup flawed?

Comment: This would probably only be a problem if your classes are calling the `ILog` inside their `Dispose` method, which seems like a design flaw. You should do as little as possible in your dispose method. Otherwise, make you `Log` class singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use NInject, but it sounds to me that you are registering the Log concrete as shared or per web request (as per the `InRequestScope` might indicate, again I do apologize for not using NInject so I am not sure what that does).

For all of the loggers I've used, NLog, Log4Net, MS' Logging Application Block, etc - they all require `Transient` registration, not `Scoped`, because they take the superclass that initiated them to write out in the log as the calling class.

As far as dispose order, I don't think you can control that with any IoC container because the object cannot be disposed in different orders if another class still has a reliance.  I ran into the same issues when I first started with IoC Containers years ago and thought, "Yeah, I'll register everything as scoped!"  Hehe, that didn't work out very well.

I would say your objects just need to be registered differently.  Only scope the items you really need scoped, everything else as `transients` or `singletons`.  I usually follow the pattern of:

> Code everything `singleton` and code `thread-safe`.
>   If not thread-safe make it a `transient` and register it as such.

If I not using a `unit-of-work` pattern with my `ORM`, I will typically register my ORM containers as `Scoped` so they can track the object changes for the life of the request, and SaveChanges() latter (e.g. Entity Framework 4, or NHibernate's Session, etc).

Comment: Thank you - I figured I was going about this wrong. Guess I have more reading / planning to do.